# setTimeout is not running only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide signup popup and display login popup by clicking 'login' link on signup modal. Which is working fine BUT problem is that setTimeout is keep opening login popup after each 1 second whereas I want to have 1 second pause and simply execute it only once.
I've used clearTimeout(), it doesn't open login popup even one time.
Please guide me. Thanks in advance!
This is my script:

```
var Tid;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    //trigger login link on signup popup
    jQuery("#register-form #login-modal a").attr("href",
        "javascript:void(0);");

    jQuery("#register-form #login-modal").click(function () {
        jQuery("#register-modal-wrap").find(".mfp-close").trigger("click");
        openLoginModal();
    });

    function openLoginModal() {
        Tid = setTimeout("jQuery('#login-modal a').trigger('click')", 1000);
        //clearTimeout(Tid);
    }
});
```

Comment: in your timeout, you recursively trigger another click, so it will loop.

Comment: there is no need for the function call `openLoginModal()`.

Comment: share your html or provide fiddle .

Comment: You have not actually asked a question - try using a question mark.  And what on earth is "... not running only once" even supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

As @Thilo has pointed out that there is a recursive triggering of click event in your code which is causing the openLoginModal() function to be called, again and again, the only way to stop that is by making sure that openLoginModal() function is called only once. This should fix the issue.

```
var Tid;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //trigger login link on signup popup
    jQuery("#register-form #login-modal a").attr("href",
        "javascript:void(0);");
    jQuery("#register-form #login-modal").click(function () {
        jQuery("#register-modal-wrap").find(".mfp- close").trigger("click");
        if (typeof Tid === 'undefined') {
            Tid = setTimeout(openLoginModal, 1000);
        }
    });

    function openLoginModal() {
        clearTimeout(Tid);
        jQuery('#login-modal a').trigger('click');
    }
});
```